# boost shared_ptr casting to void*

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm using libev which requires casting my data to a void* to be in compliance with their predefined structs. I need to cast boost::shared_ptr to a void* and then cast the void* back to a boost::shared_ptr. Here is my code to do that

```
void foo(boost::shared_ptr<string>& a_string)
{
 void* data = (void*)a_string.get();
 boost::shared_ptr<string> myString((string*)data);
}
```

I'm pretty sure this works fine, however the way my code is setup I believe all shared_ptr references to my string are going out of scope as this casting method does not increase the use_count and thus shared_ptr is freeing the memory while I still need it.

Is there a way to manually increment/decrement the use_count? Ideally I would increment the use_count when I cast to a void*, pass my void* to another function, cast the void* back to a shared_ptr and decrement the use_count.

Or if anyone knows another solution to this problem I could use any help.

Comment: You could store the watcher in a class which contains both a watcher and a `shared_ptr`. This would ensure that the lifetime of the watcher would be matched or exceeded by the lifetime of the object owned by the `shared_ptr`. Also, why not store the address of the `shared_ptr` itself rather than storing the address of the pointed-to object?

Comment: I found a hack around by making a struct that contains the shared_ptr and casting the struct to a void*. Not sure how I feel about this solution yet. Also, I saw in a forum somewhere that you shouldn't use the address of the shared_ptr.

Comment: @user1229962: What are you passing the `void*` to?

Comment: The void* gets passed back to a SharedPointer<string> on an event callback. The original SharedPointers are all out of scope by then. I think I will just have to allocate a shared_ptr on the heap and pass that to the void, then delete it inside of the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real way to do this to allocate a `shared_ptr` somewhere that will live for long enough, and then set the `void*` to point to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you cast a `void*` back to a `boost::shared_ptr`, it will be a new shared pointer, not linked to any other shared pointers that also point to the memory pointed to by the `` `void* `` variable.

What I think you need to do is add `enabled_shared_from_this` support to the classes you are thinking of using with shared_ptrs with that code.

This allows you to get a shared_ptr that will share ownership with existing shared_ptrs through a member function (`shared_from_this`) on your class.

See the [boost enabled_shared_from_this docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `weak_ptr` :

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
weak_ptr<int> q(p);
```

**Edit:** Sorry I did not read the question properly; you could try to keep it in scope so it does not get cleaned up

**Update:** A weak pointer may actually work if you reference the variable after your call because then the compiler cant optimise the destruction of the `a_string` shared_ptr (hence prevent decr refcount to zero -> release) before you make use of the underlying pointer

so you could do this:

```
void foo(boost::shared_ptr<string>& a_string)
{
 void* data = (void*)a_string.get();
 boost::shared_ptr<string> myString((string*)data);
 weak_ptr<string> temp(a_string); // prevent destruction before above line
 // or reference a_string in any meaningless way that CANT be optimised out 
 // pre-emptively by the compiler
}
```

`a_string` might still need to referenced somewhere outside of `foo` depending on the context and what you are doing with the void pointer (and if it creates a new copy or operates on the void data)

Comment: A weak_ptr doesn't increment the use_count so the memory would still be freed. How would a weak_ptr help?